# Advertising in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, admob

What you recommend for advertising platform not in the USA.
iAd is ot seding ads outside the USA.
I'v tried AdMob, ad it also seems not to work. Most of the time it fails to show up an and, ad when showing it shows only one ad again and again (some hotel booking)
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Google Mobile Ads](http://www.google.com/mobileads/)?

I would recommend not sticking to one platform as such. You have a particular service fill in ads but if that doesn't have ads for you then, query some other platform, if that doesn't the next one.

```
# Pseudo-code
if GoogleMobileAds:
    # Code to use Google Mobile Ads
else if iAd:
    # Code to use iAd
else if AdMob:
    # Code to use AdMob
else:
    # Your own promotion or whatever is your last option
```

**Edit:** You may have to handle transitions and animations on your own. You may also have to create a new `AdMobView` for every ad request you make. Following is a quote from [this](http://groups.google.com/group/admob-iphone-sdk/browse_thread/thread/d856ee54e465004a?pli=1) Google Groups discussion.

> If you require feedback from the SDK for every ad request, we suggest 
>   that you create a new AdMobView for every ad request you make.  If 
>   using this particular method, you will have to handle view transitions 
>   (and animations) between the two ads yourself, as well as cleaning up 
>   each AdMobView object when you no longer need it. If you require feedback from the SDK for every ad request, we suggest 
>   that you create a new AdMobView for every ad request you make.  If 
>   using this particular method, you will have to handle view transitions 
>   (and animations) between the two ads yourself, as well as cleaning up 
>   each AdMobView object when you no longer need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am not sure if this will work for me. The reason is because I am using the ad in a tableview. When I am getting the message didFailToRecieveAd, it is too late to place another ad. Am I wrong?

Comment: I am afraid I didn't quite get you there.

Comment: I found a Google Group [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/admob-iphone-sdk/browse_thread/thread/d856ee54e465004a?pli=1) which would be useful.

Comment: It's never too late to place a different ad.  Just remove the other one from the `superview` or table cell/header/footer and add a new view in it's place.

Comment: IWasRobbed and Ashish, thank you. You're right. This solves the problem.

Comment: In my google AdSense account I cannot see any refernce to set an iPhone ad

Comment: @Meir: If "this solves the problem" you might as well accept is a solution. (Hint, the tick mark on the left). ;)

Comment: Also as noted in the answer, visit http://www.google.com/mobileads/ to  know about Google's equivalent service.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Smart AdServer, because  in my opinion, this is the best all-in-one mobile adserving tool.

It's both an adserver (where you can program your own ads on inventory you have sell by your own) and a mobile advertising platform ( it's connected to main global adnetworks through backfills. And most of the are compliant with backfills, this is not the case for every ad server, I'd recommend that you check.

It is just an SDK (compatible i0S 5 and less), also compatible with iPad.

Programming is really easy, and formats are really cool, innovative, so you can get high CPM from them (you can check by your own downloading the iPhone app, or on [this gallery](http://smartadserver.com/gallery/mobile).

You can monitor campaigns in real time, directly in [an iPhone app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/smart-adserver-dashboard/id487176494?mt=8).